# Error while calling 'sed' from spawn

Tags: unix, sed, send, spawn

I am trying to execute `send "sed -e\'s/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g\' test_log"`
 from within the spawn but it is throwing me this error:

```
bash-4.1$ invalid command name "0-9A-F"
while executing
"0-9A-F"
invoked from within
"send "sed -e\'s/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g\' test_log""
(file "./test.sh" line 19)
```

I have added `\` too for escape character in `sed`, but still it is not working.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Cyrus: yes, I am using this in a script with spawn.

Answer (score 0):

Don't escape the single quote in sed
i.e. use

```
sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' test_log
```

and not

```
sed -e\'s/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g\' test_log
```

Comment: Still not working. Same error.

    invalid command name "0-9A-F"
    while executing
"0-9A-F"
    invoked from within
"send "sed -e's/%\([0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\)/\\\\\x\1/g' test_log""
    (file "./fetch_log.sh" line 19)